# Can you use 'would not been' instead of 'would not have been" in "the great clock would not have been erected"?

Tags: tense

> If the Houses of Parliament had not been burned down in 1834, **the
> great clock would not have been erected**.

Can you use 'would not been' instead of 'would not have been'?

Comment: No, "'would not been'" is ungrammatical.

Comment: How about ' would not had been'?

Comment: No, "'would not had been'" is ungrammatical.

Comment: You will find it hard to believe, but I have decided to move into the country.
Can you tell me what is the it mean?

Comment: Please ask a new question about that!

Comment: I can only ask one question every 40 minuntes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only   "would not have been" or  "wouldn't have been"  is accepted as grammatically correct.